# BigInteger.intValue() equivalent in C#

Tags: java, c#, biginteger

I am trying to translate a java code into C# and encountered a problem working with BigInteger operations. I found several resources on BigInteger implementation in C# and the intValue itself. But no clue on BigInteger.intValue equivalent in C#.
The definition in Java is:

> *Converts this BigInteger to an int. Thisconversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section
> 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification:if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, **only the low-order 32 bits are returned**.Note
> that this conversion can lose information about theoverall magnitude
> of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the **opposite
> sign.***

But getting similar results using (int) in C# results in error:

> *Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.*

I also tried to use only the low bytes with no success
It would be appreciated if someone helps

Comment: You can only convert a Big to an Integer when the value is within the limits of an integer.  This error will occur if the number is too large either positive or negative.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Why would they want to know how to do something in Java when their question is about translating something from Java to C#?

Comment: @jdweng They are looking for the equivalent of casting `long` to `int` where it will not fail and instead just truncates bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Java’s behaviour, mask out the lower bits of the value and convert the result:

```cs
int result = (int) (uint) (bi & uint.MaxValue);
```

(This is using the [implicit `UInt32` to `BigInteger` conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.op_implicit?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger_op_Implicit_System_UInt32__System_Numerics_BigInteger), and the [explicit conversion for the other way round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.op_explicit?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger_op_Explicit_System_Numerics_BigInteger__System_UInt32))